# Php undefined variables error

Tags: php, aptana

I know the question was previously posted but I guess there is some change in the php new release.
I am trying to find the code for a form limiting the users for putting excess text in the form of guestbook

my code is:

```
<?php
if (mysql_connect('localhost','root','')&&mysql_select_db('phpsearch') )
{
    $time = time();
    $errors = array();

    if (isset 
($_POST['guestbook_name'],$_POST['guestbook_email'],$_POST['guestbook_message']))
    {
        $guestbook_name = htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_name']);
        $guestbook_email = htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_email']);
        $guestbook_meassage = htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_message']);

        if (empty ($guestbook_name) || empty($guestbook_email) || empty ($guestbook_message))
        {
            $errors[] = "All information required";
        }   

        if (strlen($guestbook_name)>25 || strlen($guestbook_email)>255 || strlen($guestbook_message)>400)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Exceed limit length';
        }
```

I am using aptana text editor and named this file as a .php extension but the text turns white after the >25 even if I ignore the color the error is displayed saying

```
Notice: Undefined variable: guestbook_message in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\chalo_guestbook.php on line 51
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo above:

```
 $guestbook_meassage = htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_message']);
```

Additionally I'd suggest using `htmlentities` only when displaying and saving raw data into your database. That way you can easily build an Edit-Form and retrieve the original-text.

Comment: but what about ppl who put spam links in the text box

Comment: "suggest using htmlentities only when displaying"

Comment: The aptana color changes white after ">25" while typing does that mean anything?

Comment: Probably misconfiguration. Maybe it sees the `>` as a closing HTML-Tag.